# Unknown account while trying to send transaction via OptimismProvider

Tags: web3-providers, sendtransaction, ethers.js

I'm trying to make use of OptimismProvider to sign the transaction on Mumbai Matic. I'm making use of `provider.send("eth_sendTransaction", [hexTxn])` and instantiating provider object by:
`const provider = new OptimismProvider("MUMBAI_MATIC_RPC_URL", new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum))`
where hexTxn is the hexlified version of the txn format:
`tx = { to: 'Contract Address', nonce: 0, gasLimit: 0, gasPrice: 0, data: '0x00', value: 0, chainId: 1 }`

I'm making use of the below versions:
etherjs: 5.0.30
@eth-optimism/provider: 0.0.1-alpha.14

And I'm getting the below error:

[image: Unknown account on eth_sendTransaction]

Comment: It is not sure if Optimistic Rollups are enabled on Matic TestNet. Could you please verify it before proceeding further on this.